# Equivalent of UIModalTransitionStyle for horizontal push transition?

Tags: swift

I'm looking to use UIModalTransitionStyle to pass context into my navigation stack with pushViewController. It's working for modal thanks to

```
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
```

Is there any equivalent to this for pushViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

For additional controller transition animations I recommend this library:

https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero

and then you can push your navigation controller like this:

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.hero.modalAnimationType = .slideLeft
hero.replaceViewController(with: vc)
```

It has plenty animation types which are documented on their page.